# set headers in cloudinary to avoid tainted canvas

Tags: php, canvas, cross-domain, cloudinary

i'm making a simple drawing app in javascript for the client side and php for saving and loading. The app is hosted on heroku and the saved pictures are hosted on cloudinary. When the app loads a saved picture from cloudinary and draws it on the canvas, then the canvas becomes tainted because of cross-domain.
I'm using the cloudinary php-API to save the image

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($canvasToDataUrl, array("public_id" => $saveName));
```

I tried adding a row in the options array with a few different syntaxes like

```
, "headers" => "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"
```

I believe this header is not supported by the API, the supported headers are 'link' and 'X-Robots-Tag'.

Is there a way to force my saved pictures to have the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"?

Answer (score 3):

Cloudinary returns the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, so it should work for CORS.
Here's an example which demonstrates Cloudinary images usage in Canvas:
https://jsfiddle.net/137ptoja/

For using the `toDataURL` method, then note that when having requests to an HTTP URL from an HTTPS page, this is disallowed by CORS. 
Also, if there is a cookie for the domain, the request is not considered anonymous and so it's blocked.

Here's an example the works:
https://jsfiddle.net/taragano/td0eLafc/